# Get virtual machine facts using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am running a ansible playbook to get the status of virtual machine in azure my playbook look likes

```yaml
- name: Get facts by name
  azure_rm_virtualmachine_facts:
    resource_group: startAnsible
    name: startAnsible-vm
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ659.png)

is there any method to get the facts/information of a virtual machine in azure.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a task but from the error, you are trying to execute it as a play.

Playbook files contains a list of plays and each play execute a list of tasks (and/or roles).

So you need to put your task in a play:

```yaml
- name: The play
  hosts: <the target machine from your inventory>
  tasks:
    - name: Get facts by name
      azure_rm_virtualmachine_facts:
        resource_group: startAnsible
        name: startAnsible-vm
```

Comment: Not showing any results or output.

Comment: None at all?! You should have at least the playbook output. Then, the module `azure_rm_virtualmachine_facts` is just computing facts, you need to `register` them in a variable to use in next tasks.

Comment: Can you please write how to register them in a variable!

Answer (score 0):

Within the initial error message the correct module is referenced [`azure_rm_virtualmachine_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_module.html#examples) to get the virtual machine facts, whereby in the code snippet a probably old alias is used.

**Further Links**

- [Ansible Issue #38081 - "New module request: `azure_rm_virtualmachine_facts`"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/38081)